# How to start/stop windows service using Qt?

Tags: qt, windows-services

Lets imagine situation: I have running windows service named "Test". Now I want to **stop** or **start** (if it's stopped) this service using Qt app.

How can I do it?

Note:

> I don't want to call cmd and use "net start" and "net stop" commands!

Comment: With such restrictions Windows API is the only way, AFAIK : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682108(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why do you think that it should be done with Qt? Why not WinAPI?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the corresponding Qt Solution https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice

Then you can do something like:

```
QtServiceController controller("Test");
controller.stop();
controller.start();
```

Comment: This is a solution to create a your own service. But @j-doe is asking how to control an existing one.

Comment: no, it is made to control services as well. The `QtServiceController` class is to control services, while `QtService` is meant to create one. It's simply both part of the same library.

Comment: Can these services be used in QT installer framework (ControlScript.qs)? I want to stop the windows service while uninstalling from QT installer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Qt does not provide such kind on API.

You need to look into WinAPI solution.
There is [an example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms686335(v=vs.85).aspx) how to stop a service. Im sure you could figure how to use same approach to start it.

Additionally, you could also check a [much smaller example](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/07/09/a-simple-example-of-starting-and-stopping-a-service-in-windows-using-c/) how to both start and stop a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `sc` command ([this page](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-start-and-stop-services-windows-10#mange_services_cmd_windows10) has some usage info or just type `sc` on the command prompt).

```
sc stop Test
sc start Test
```

So:

```
QProcess::execute("sc", { "stop", "Test" });
QProcess::execute("sc", { "start", "Test" });
```

Note that you need to be running in an elevated context to control most services.

You could also use `net` instead of `sc` if you prefer, same syntax for starting and stopping.

The parameter needs to be the service key name, not the display name; so if you only have the display name you can run `sc query` or `sc GetKeyName "Display Name"` and parse the output.